# Why God doesn't forgive the sin of Shirk?

Tags: shirk

AlhamdoLELLAH I am a Muslim.and I know that Allah never forgives the sin of Shirk.

If Allah wants He forgives all kind of sins, then why He doesn't forgive the sin of Shirk.? I want to have a Logical reason.

May Mercy and Blessing of Allah be on all of you :)

Comment: If a person abstains from shirk and ask for forgiveness, inshallah he/she will be forgiven. It is only when someone dies as a mushrik, that the window of forgiveness for shirk ends.

Answer (score 2):

Shirk in the Islamic terminology is "ascribing a partner or rival to Allah in Lordship (ruboobiyyah), worship or in His names and attributes."

According to the definition above, the person who commits Shirk basically associate a partner by worshiping a person, something, animal or deny his existence and Allah is not creator of the universe. They people doing that associate the universe as a partner whom created this life that we are in. Shirk is belief sin that settle in one person heart. Remember that associating partners means that the entity that had something attached to it is Incomplete or in need. Which is totally opposite to the belief in God.

Coming back to the verse that you have mentioned, this applies in the day of Judgement. What that means, that if a person commit a certain sin but he came on the day of Judgement believing that there is no God but the Creator (Allah: arabic word meaning the One God). God might forgive his sins with his well. The following verse shows that:

> قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَى أَنْفُسِهِمْ لا تَقْنَطُوا مِنْ رَحْمَةِ اللَّهِ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ جَمِيعًا إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ (53)
>
> Say: "O ‘Ibâdî (My slaves) who have transgressed against themselves (by committing evil deeds and sins)! Despair not of the Mercy of Allâh: verily, Allâh forgives all sins. Truly He is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.[2](http://qurancomplex.gov.sa/quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?l=arb&t=TABARY&nSora=39&nAya=53#39_53)

May Allah forgive us all. But if someone came in the day of Judgement and committed Shirk then this will not be forgiven. This verse is a warning for any person who has some form of association with God to repent before he or she dies. But it's not an invite for people to commit other sins too. Because you will go into the region which were your sins might take you to hell fire. May Allah forgive us and guide us to the right path and belief.

Here after is my personal understanding to the reasoning behind this. If someone commits Shirk, he or she is basically denying the completeness of God by associating partners or ignoring him totally. And that person is asking God after that to forgive him, that would be contradictory for his or her belief. As he or she ignored him or denied him in the first place. God forbid His mercy on those and doomed them to go to hell fire because they have ignored, denied, associated partners with him. Remember that God is all Capable and all powerful. Nothing happens in this universe except with his well. Once someone associate partners that limits Gods abilities. And after that you are asking for his forgiveness. It's similar to swearing someone with the worst words and characters, then ask that person: "Oh, please give me money.". This example is not even compared to the God.

Any success in answering is from God and any mistakes is from me and Shaytan. And Allah knows best.

**References:**

- http://islamqa.info/en/34817
- [http://qurancomplex.gov.sa](http://qurancomplex.gov.sa/Quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?nSora=4&t=tabary&l=arb&nAya=48#4_48)
- [http://qurancomplex.gov.sa/quran](http://qurancomplex.gov.sa/quran/tafseer/Tafseer.asp?l=arb&t=TABARY&nSora=39&nAya=53#39_53)

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this applies when someone dies in that state.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly speaking, actually, Shirk is against Towhid (monotheism) and actually they are opposable. In truth, there is a sort of Hijab or obstacle for entrance of Allah’s Rahmah and blessing in the Mushrik heart. Subsequently Moshrik is not eligible for getting the Rahmah and Maqferah of Allah (during s/he is Mushrik).

As it has mentioned in Surah an-Nisa’:48

> إِنَّ اللَّـهَ لَا يَغْفِرُ أَن يُشْرَكَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرُ مَا دُونَ
>   ذَٰلِكَ لِمَن يَشَاءُ ۚ وَمَن يُشْرِكْ بِاللَّـهِ فَقَدِ افْتَرَىٰ
>   إِثْمًا عَظِيمًا ﴿٤٨﴾
>
> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives
>   what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others
>   with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin. (48)

Let’s illustrate more concerning the issue of Shirk. Actually, Shirk (and Kufr) are considered as an obstacle for the relationship to the source of Khair (Blessing), it would reach fulfilment due to excess of the sins and barbarity. That’s why Allah said:
ان الله لا يغفر ان يشرك به و يغفر مادون ذلك لمن يشاء

Hence, malicious Shirk (and Kufr) won’t be forgiven. On the other hand there are many people who have hearty and inner faith, but do shirk due to ignorance, But:
They’ll accept the right (legitimacy) humbly if it is present to them. But the other group will be eligible of torture who their Shirk would be considered as a malicious Shirk. I hope my response be constructive at least to some extent.

---

**References:**

[http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/4:48)

[http://www.askquran.ir](http://www.askquran.ir/thread25227.html)

Answer (score 0):

Shirk is applicable only to a believer. 
God created you and if you know this to be a fact then committing shirk youre guilty and hence punished. What can you expect from someone you don't even believe in.
Don't forget Allah was challenged by satan who said he would lead astray his creation. So after knowing all this you still do shirk then please don't expect mercy as Allah has made it clear he will not forgive. Disrespecting your creator then man up to pay for your stupidy and arrogance.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Unlike the typical internet forum we expect answers here to be well elaborated, focused on answering OP's question and **claims supported by evidences** (See [answer]).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Allah is merciful and does not need us or our prayings. If you say Allah will not forgive you because He created you and you ignored him, to me, it is like giving to Allah some sort of ego, which is a human weakness and cannot be attributed to Allah. Yes, Allah may not forgive you because of shirk, but I don't think because He is angry or anything. Shirk by itself may cause some other effects which can lead someone to badness. In one comment, it is written "if you are a believer on the beginning" as a condition, which I find very appropirate. Judging a good Budhist person and sending him to hell by this interpretation does not feel right to me. Allah is all merciful.

Answer (score 0):

**In the name of God, the Beneficent, the Merciful**

**All perfect praise be to God, the Lord of the worlds. I testify that there is none worthy of worship except God and that Muhammad 
￼
 is His slave and Messenger.**

---

**Your question:** Why God doesn’t forgive shirk?

**Answer:** First, you need to understand what’s the meaning of Shirk. Shirk, (Arabic: “making a partner [of someone]”), in Islām, idolatry, polytheism, and the association of God with other deities. If you commit shirk, then your denying His Oneness, because He has told us there’s no God but He.

God Says:

> ”Those who reject (Truth), among the People of the Book and among the Polytheists, will be in Hell-fire, to dwell therein (for aye). They are the worst of creatures." **(al-Bayyina, 98/6).**

But He has created us so that we can worship Him and this life is a test from Him, but He doesn’t even need our belief nor our prayers, because He Says:

> O mankind, you are those in need of God, while God is the Free of need, the Praiseworthy. [(**35:15**)](https://quran.com/35/15)

And He doesn’t like the indidels( those who commit Shirk, reject His Signs, mock and disbelieve in His books) according to this verse:

> ”That He may reward those who have believed and done righteous deeds out of His bounty. Indeed, He does not like the disbelievers.” [(**30:45**)](https://quran.com/30/45-55)

So you see? it’s a test from God, those who believe will be rewarded, or punished first and be rewarded after this, and those who disbelieved and died upon it, will never ever get the reward but only the severe punishment. As per the the verse:

> ”And certainly, We shall test you with something of fear, hunger, loss of wealth, lives and fruits, but give glad tidings to the patient.” [**islamqa**](https://islamqa.info/en/41703)